White screen after add _framework/blazor.server.js
I am working on a project which I created. When running the project for the first time and implementing the designs in the app, I tried to execute a C# method from the frontend where I did not receive a response, since the code was reviewed and is correct for it to be executed. I investigated and found the solution of adding  in _Layout.cshtml. The problem is that when you add this line to that file and run the project, it loads, shows the normal design for a second and then a blank screen, leaving the project without any errors.
My teammates have executed exactly the same project, with the same database in their environments and it works perfectly for them.
Withe Screen
C# .Net 6.0
DotNet Version: 7.0.403
Blazor 6.0
Project: Blazor Server
I tried removing the layout script and my app looks normal and works, but the c# buttons don't, which is why when investigating I saw that a solution was to use the script.

Can you give me the code snippet about the c# buttons method  ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
